# How to redirect user to a different controller on refreshing the page

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, controller

I am working on codeigniter. I am implementing signin functionality and when user signs in i call this controller

```
function validate_credentials()
{   
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query==1)
    {
        $data = array 
        (
            'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $email=$data['username'];

        $this->session->set_userdata('email_of_user',$email);
        $this->load->model('search_peoplee');
        $data['userid']= $this->search_peoplee->get_userid_from_email($email);
        foreach ($data['userid'] as $row)
            {
                $one=$row->userid;
            }
        $data['result']=$this->membership_model->friend_notify($one);

        $data['count']=$this->search_peoplee->get_friends_count($one);
        $this->load->model('search_peoplee');
        $data['values']= $this->search_peoplee->get_notifications($one);
        $data['count_notify']=$this->search_peoplee->get_notifications_count($one);
        $this->session->set_userdata('lookatit','no');
        $this->load->view('home_screen',$data);
    }
    elseif($query==2)
    {
        $data['main_content']='email_not_found';
        $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->error_index();
    }
}
```

this validates the credentials and stores a session, this controller calls a model "$this->membership_model->validate();" which picks the value form view and check that if user exists, the problem is when i retype the address it takes me to the login page and says sign in again as the model reads empty values. How to avoid this. help!!!

Answer (score 0):

after you have authenticated, how about setting a session variable.
so,

```
$this->session->set_userdata('authenticated',TRUE);
```

then in the controller, first check if the user is authenticated and do a redirect, otherwise go to the validate_credentials method  ??

Comment: user is redirected to that page after signing in, when the user is on that page he is already signed in, now if he refreshes I want to call a different controller function

Comment: do you mean with a redirect(), and use a flag to determine when to redirect?